# POST запрос [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, post

Есть post запрос в js, возвращает **"followed"**, по условию должен перезагрузить страницу, но js все равно выполняет функцию else, и в alert результат **"followed**". В чем может быть ошибка?

```
$.post("/index.php?plugin=follow&act=follow", {user_id: user_id}, function(result){
   if(result === 'followed') {
      
      // reload Page
      window.location.reload();
   } else {
      
      // show Error
      alert(result);
   }
});
```

Comment: Если честно, мы вам не верим)

Comment: Что покажет `[...result].map(x => charCodeAt(0))`?

Comment: `console.log(result);`

Comment: @Igor, так же followed

Comment: Я уже схожу с ума в чем бл может быть проблема

Comment: в том что буквы не совпадают? скопируй followed из js и вставь его на сервере

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, там может вообще bom быть - потому я коды и спросил, с не строку.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский копировал, не помогает. На всех таких в js запросах у меня такая беда, раньше все работало.

Answer (score 0):

Короче попытался вместо запроса на

```
$.post("/index.php?plugin=follow&act=follow"
```

сделать напрямую на index.php

```
$.post("/index.php?follow"
```

и в нем

```
if(isset($_GET['follow'])){
    echo 'followed';
    die();
}
```

Все заработало! Буду искать причину